# How to use time in calculations (half hours)

Tags: java

I want to make a program that's checking if an input is greater than *8h30m*. How do I accomplish this? I thought maybe about `java.util.Calendar` or `Date` but I don't know how those things work.

Comment: To help you we are going to need an example list of input. Is there a specific part where you are stuck?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) from Java 8:

```
String input = "8h";
Duration duration = Duration.parse("PT" + input);
Duration compared = Duration.ofHours(8).plus(Duration.ofMinutes(30));
int compare = duration.compareTo(compared); // -1
// compare would be 0 for input="8h30m" and 1 for input="8h40m"
```

**Edit** - You can substract times as well, get the seconds for example:

```
Duration diff = duration.minus(compared);
int seconds = diff.getSeconds();
```

Comment: (this count for all people that helped me in this questoin) I am really thankful but my problem was that i needed to subtract the two time for instance 11h30m - 8h30m

Comment: Youri, see my answer.

Comment: @Youri: you can do everything with the duration. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Joda Timer

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

You can use DateTime for that and us function isAfter for your case.

Comment: I heard much about this but it seem like I can import it any I idea why

Comment: @Youri - it's an external library that you'll have to add to your classpath (for example by adding it as dependency in Maven's POM, if you're using Maven)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to check if the current time is before another time, you can do this:

```
public Boolean foo() {
    Calendar currentlyCal = Calendar.getInstance(); // This is the currently time.
    Calendar calToCheck = Calendar.getInstance();
    calToCheck.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calToCheck.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    return currentlyCal.before(calToCheck); // or use after() instead of before() if it's what you want.
}
```

EDIT

The difference:

```
public void getDifference(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
    long diff = cal2.getTimeInMillis() - cal.getTimeInMillis();
    long seconds = diff/1000;
    long hour = seconds/3600;
    seconds = seconds%3600;
    long minutes = seconds/60;
    seconds = seconds%60;
    // .. do something
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Do You have a solution when you want to subtract a time from a time

Comment: The `Calander` class is old and in Java 8 there is much better alternatives available in the `java.time` package. Don't use `Calander` if you can avoid it!

Comment: Any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: Youri, you can use `cal1.getTimeInMillis() - cal2.getTimeInMillis()`. It returns the difference of milliseconds between the two dates. Having this difference, you have to transform it to hours, minutes and so on.

Comment: @Lii I agree you, but he asked for any solution with Calendar.

Comment: @Lii everytime someone asks for a solution with a specific class, and I give a solution with another class, every guy on SO starts the speech "he didn't ask you for this class, he asked for the other class. bla bla bla".. So I stoped answering with what I think it's the best, and instead I answer with what the author asked. :)

Comment: Youri, I thought you were asking for the time 8h30min, and not the difference. See EDIT of my post.